# How can I combine polymorphism with unwrapping in Jackson?

Tags: java, json, jackson

I'm writing annotated model classes for json serialization/deserialization using jackson.

I have a json that contains a map, where the key is an enum and the value can be different types (including arrays) depending on key value.

A simplified example, this is what I need:

```
{
 "key1": "string value",
 "key2": [{"id":"1", "value": "test1"}, {"id":"2", "value": "test2"}]
}
```

I have tried, and I get this:

```
{
  "KEY1": {"value": "string value"},
  "KEY2": {"list": [{"id": "1", "value": "test1"}, {"id": "2", "value": "test2"}]}
}
```

So, unwrapping does not work.

Could anyone tell me what I am doing wrong ?

Here is the code:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        HashMap<Keys, ValueType> map = new HashMap<>();

        map.put(Keys.KEY1, new StringValue("string value"));

        map.put(Keys.KEY2, new ListValue( Arrays.asList(new Element[] {
                new Element("1", "test1"),
                new Element("2", "test2")
        } )));

        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        String s = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(map);

        System.out.println(s);

    }
}

public enum Keys {

    KEY1("key1"),
    KEY2("key2");

    private String value;

    Keys(String s) {
        this.value = s;
    }
}

public interface ValueType {

}

public class StringValue implements ValueType {

    @JsonUnwrapped
    private String value;

    public StringValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}

public class ListValue implements ValueType {

    @JsonUnwrapped
    private List<Element> list;

    public ListValue(List<Element> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }

    public List<Element> getList() {
        return list;
    }

    public void setList(List<Element> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }
}

public class Element {

    @JsonProperty
    private String id;
    @JsonProperty
    private String value;

    public Element(String id, String value) {
        this.id = id;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can annotate the classes' getters methods with the [`JsonValue`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.12/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonValue.html) annotation  that indicates that *the value of annotated accessor is to be used as the single value to serialize for the instance, instead of the usual method of collecting properties of value*:

```
public class StringValue implements ValueType {

    @JsonUnwrapped
    private String value;

    public StringValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
    @JsonValue //<-- added annotation to the original getter method
    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}

public class ListValue implements ValueType {

    @JsonUnwrapped
    private List<Element> list;

    public ListValue(List<Element> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }

    @JsonValue //<-- added annotation to the original getter method
    public List<Element> getList() {
        return list;
    }

    public void setList(List<Element> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }
}
```